# Get separate audio from each participant in a zoom meeting

Tags: audio, zoom-sdk

I want to access audio from a zoom meeting (in real time) from each participant separately. My goal is to get the audio matrix for each participant of the meeting and then mix it myself, preferably using python or matlab.